# Custom Header colors on Datagrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, actionscript

Is this possible?  Ive seen many examples of it done with Flex components...  What im trying to do is a have a custom color for each column header item in a datagrid component.  I have found ways to set the all the header colors to a specific color, but not individuals...

I can do something like this: assayGrid.setStyle("headerUpSkin", calcIcon); but it will set all the headers.  What i'd like to do is something like this approach which doesnt work, assayGrid.columns[0].setStyle("headerUpSkin", calcIcon);

Answer (score 2):

Write a custom header renderer (extending DefaultGridHeaderRenderer) with a color parameter. Assign this to GridColumn's headerRenderer field.
You can use ClassFactory to generate the renderer for different colors.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom DefaultGridHeaderRenderer component

and include the following code

```
private var myRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(myComponentHeader);
```